# Spring Boot and React can't load index.html

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a simple web application using `create-react-app` and Spring Boot, but spring can't find `index.html` in resources.

React's `build` folder is copied to `target` by `maven-resources-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
           ...
            <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                ...
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/app/build</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                ...     
</plugin>
```

**This is my project structure:**

[image]

[image]

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class BasicController {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String index() {
      return "index";
   }
}
```

Get request to `localhost:8080` returns `404`. Could you please point me where am i mistaken.

**UPDATE:**

Managed to make it working by changing React's build output directory in maven plugin to
`${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`
and `return "index"` to `return index.html`.

Comment: I kept my index.html in the static dir but just tacked on ".html" to index when integrating my react app like so: @RequestMapping(value = "/")
 public String index() {
  return "index.html";
 }.  I am still not sure why "index" alone was not enough.  Most examples I have seen just say "index".  Perhaps it's because I don't have webMvc set?  I have a pure restful back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's maybe not the precise answer your question, but I would try example [from the docs](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot).

> Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:
>
> /META-INF/resources/
>
> /resources/
>
> /static/
>
> /public/
>
> In the case of the Consuming a RESTful Web Service with jQuery guide, we included index.html and hello.js files in the /public/ folder. This means that not only does Spring Boot offer a simple approach to building Java or Groovy apps, you can also use it to easily deploy client-side JavaScript code and test it within a real web server environment!

Just copy the content of CRA build directory to Spring Boot `public` directory (make sure index.html is at the `/public/index.html`).

If this works then try to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Spring boot backend with reactjs frontend. I solved it by adding a view resolver (thymeleaf) and copying the generated react build resources to `outputDirectory/templates` directory like below

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/templates">
                                    <fileset
                                        dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/javascript/build" />
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```